Updating NAS array
My personal D-Link two disk NAS is getting old and I am concerned that if the board in the chassis fails the two mirrored disks will not be readable in a different brand.  Is this the case?  If so, apart from copying everything off onto another drive and repopulating a new array are there any workarounds?  Cheers.
